# Rogue DNS Entry Causing Problems

Tags: macos, dns

I'm running Mac OS X (wired connection) and on a really crappy ISP.  Because of this I've set my DNS servers to use OpenDNS, which is generally much more responsive.  However, for some reason 192.168.1.1 is at the top of my DNS search order (confirmed via /etc/resolv.conf and nslookup).  The problem is that it's not listed anywhere in my network configuration.  It might be coming from DHCP, but I've read that if it is it should be last in the list.  How do I remove this altogether, or at the very least force Mac OS X to always try it last?

### Additional Information:

Very strange.  When I go into System Preferences, only the OpenDNS servers are listed.  I've checked every adapter listed, whether they are enabled or not (including Bluetooth, Firewire, etc.).  When I run `networksetup -getdnsservers Ethernet` it only returns the OpenDNS servers.

However if I `cat /etc/resolv.conf` I get

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

And nslookup gives me:

```
> server
Default server: 192.168.1.1
Address: 192.168.1.1#53
Default server: 208.67.222.222
Address: 208.67.222.222#53
Default server: 208.67.220.220
Address: 208.67.220.220#53
```

When I look something up in nslookup it sometimes responds with 192.168.1.1 and sometimes with an OpenDNS server.  And sometimes it times out completely due to my aforementioned crappy ISP.

Comment: Well it's probably from DHCP. Check setting on your router. Best way to solve this would be to set your router to use OpenDNS servers directly and let computers use your router as relay.

Comment: It's a shared internet connection in my building.  I don't have access to the router's DHCP settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you set your DNS to use OpenDNS?

In the Network preference pane in System Preferences, if you click Advanced... on your Airport and go to the DNS tab: What is the order that appears there? Is 192.168.1.1 in grey or black?

If the IP address is black it's been manually entered, if it's grey it came via DHCP. You can also drag and drop entries to change the order as necessary. `/etc/resolv.conf` is auto generated from these settings so changing `/etc/resolv.conf` won't stick. If you want to set the DNS servers and manage them from the command line, check out `networksetup`. (eg. `networksetup -getalldnsservers AirPort`)

Comment: Added some additional information to the post in answer to your questions. Still not sure what's going on though.

Comment: @dosboy: Which version of Mac OS X specifically and have you restarted recently?

Comment: 10.6.4.  Just rebooted, and everything is exactly the same.  No changes.

Comment: Just for clarification, right after you edit your DNS settings in System Preferences and hit Apply - if you check resolv.conf has 192.168.1.1 been added yet?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't seem to update resolv.conf at all.  I just removed 208.67.220.220 and hit Apply, and my resolv.conf still had all 3 entries in it.

Comment: @dosboy: That's an issue - what are the permissions on /etc/resolv.conf and what happens if you modify /etc/resolv.conf yourself?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  293  6 Aug 01:27 resolv.conf`

If I try to modify it myself using vi it tells me it's read-only. If I add ! I get the following error:

`"resolv.conf" E212: Can't open file for writing`

Comment: @dosboy You'll have to run vi using sudo. eg. `sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Ok. I've edited it and removed 192.168.1.1. Ran nslookup >server and only the OpenDNS servers are listed. So that's good. So now I just wait and see if resolv.conf reverts to its previous state?

Comment: Sounds like it - doesn't explain why /etc/resolv.conf wasn't updating. That bit is bizarre.